# Jenkins Bitbucket OAuth plugin causes NullPointerException

Tags: jenkins, oauth, jenkins-plugins

I'm trying to configure jenkins locally before deploying it, however I can't seem to get the [Bitbucket OAuth plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Bitbucket+OAuth+Plugin) to work without throwing a `NullPointerException`:

`java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.acegisecurity.providers.AbstractAuthenticationToken.equals(AbstractAuthenticationToken.java:107)
    at jenkins.security.NonSerializableSecurityContext.equals(NonSerializableSecurityContext.java:62)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSession.callSessionAttributeListeners(AbstractSession.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSession.changeAttribute(AbstractSession.java:513)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.AbstractSession.setAttribute(AbstractSession.java:461)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.storeSecurityContextInSession(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:408)
    at org.acegisecurity.context.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter.java:264)
    at hudson.security.HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.doFilter(HttpSessionContextIntegrationFilter2.java:67)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:87)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:171)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.doFilter(DiagnosticThreadNameFilter.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:553)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:311)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:544)
    at winstone.BoundedExecutorService$1.run(BoundedExecutorService.java:77)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)`

Jenkins 2.19.4 is running in Docker locally.  I am remapping port 80 -> 8080.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your Jenkins is not configured correctly.

Before you enable the Bitbucket OAuth Plugin, make sure Jenkins knows its own URL:

Go to

> http://localhost/configure -> **Jenkins Location** -> **Jenkins URL**

In your case, it should probably be set to

> http://localhost/

(The URL configured there must match the URL you use to access Jenkins, otherwise a NullPointerException is thrown. For instance, if you set **Jenkins URL** to http://localhost.localdomain and then try to access Jenkins via http://localhost, an NPE is thrown.)

After that, enable the **Bitbucket OAuth Plugin** and log out.

To log in, go to http://localhost/

Comment: This was set correctly.  Also tried with a valid url and an entry in my hosts file.

Comment: @moshen, can you provide the command line you used to run the docker container (docker run ...), the value you have configured in the Jenkins Location -> Jenkins URL text area, the URL you have visited in your web browser, and whether the web browser is running on the same host where "docker run" was executed?